# Bind short json props to the long model properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json

It's a common thing that you have

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

as a model's properties and want json to look like

```
{
  "fn":"jim",
  "ln":"The Sparrow"
}
```

When you send/receive large data via ajax, you don't want properties to take half of the request body, but at the same time need something understandable in the code.
The `[JsonProperty()]` attribute doesnt work on incoming data, the default MVC model binder has no idea what is it.
Any suggessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ActionParameterAlias](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/adding-an-alias-to-an-action-parameter-for-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc/) to essentially tell model binding which passed-in values to map to which method parameters.